# How to deal with categories sorting by position?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I try to use `sortByPosition()` in the `CategoryCollection` collection during seoUrl generation. My pattern is the follow `{% for part in product.categories.sortByPosition().first.breadcrumb %}{{ part }}/{% endfor %}{{ product.translated.name|lower }}/{{ product.productNumber }}` but I don't get what I expected.

I have two categories:

- system

  - dach
  - garden
- sales

  - drei-Jahre

I add to a product two subcategories: garden and drei-Jahre. When my seoUrl template starts to generate a "SEO path" it uses sortByPosition()->first().

I expect to receive - garden
but
I actually receive - drei-Jahre

How I can get garden?

Comment: Maybe the sort position is relative to the parent, the categories have different parents...